# How to write Regex?

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have `NSString` as like this

> /:012/:^_^/:^$^ some string

How can I extract the words which starts with `/:` using Regex (`NSRegularExpression`), Kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "words"? Is `^_^` or `^$^some string` a "word"? What are your expected results?

Comment: Without regex: `let words = str.components(separatedBy: "/:")` will give you an array of words.

Comment: In Obj-C: `NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/:"];`

Comment: I would like to get /:012 , /:^_^ like this strings using Regex, later I may change those strings into emoji.

Comment: Aha, so you want to "split  keeping the delimiters as part of those split strings". Please share the code you have written so far to solve that. Also, please check if the "words" can contain a colon in them. Is it in Swift or Objective-C?

Comment: Its Objective-C , NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult *> *emoticonResults = [[StatusHelper regexEmoticon] matchesInString:text.string options:kNilOptions range:text.rangeOfAll]; , then I check the array  for (NSTextCheckingResult *emo in emoticonResults) , if result found will replace the string with emoji in desired NSRange.

Comment: You need to give some code and/or explain what are the "changing" parts, logic behind your search.

Comment: Cool, please add that to the question. So, basically, you need [something like this](https://ideone.com/7REKpm)?

Comment: Please confirm [this solution is working or not](https://ideone.com/Y8UVs6).

Comment: Thank you very much Bro.. it's working fine but for last string "/:^$^ some string" it's return like this.. How can I extract it separately.

Comment: @LiangQiang Please add `@`+`username` when providing feedback. So, what value do you expect at the end? Just `/:^$^` or `/:^$^` and `some string`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes..

Comment: @LiangQiang: Then my answer will work for you, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
NSString *pattern = @"/:\\S*?(?=/:|\\s|$)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wiWPQP/1).

**Details**:

- `/:` - a `/:` substring
- `\S*?` - zero or more chars other than whitespace, as few as possible up to (but excluding) the first occurrence of the following:
- `(?=/:|\s|$)` - either `/:` substring, or whitespace or end of string.

[Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/0N1Gyh):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *pattern = @"/:\\S*?(?=/:|\\s|$)";
NSString *string = @"/:012/:^_^/:^$^ some string";
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:range];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
   NSRange matchRange = [match range];
   NSString *m = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];
   NSLog(@"Matched string: %@", m);
}
```

Results:

```
Matched string: /:012
Matched string: /:^_^
Matched string: /:^$^
```

Comment: BTW, the regex can also be re-written as [`@"/:(?:(?!/:)\\S)*"`](https://regex101.com/r/wiWPQP/2), but it is a bit more unreadable, I think.